# Build Errror AIDE

Tags: java, android, build, aide-ide

I installed a few libs and after installation, I compile the application during the compile *I obtained this error:*

## Build error

**Packaging error:** java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.aide.ui/cache/apk/app.apk-unsigned: open failed: ENOENT(No such file or directory